# Node Js (Sequelize) - Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, findall

I try to get two column values from my mysql database.

**This is my model**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/database');

const AuthDetails = db.define('auth_details', {
    client_id : {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    client_secret : {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
},{
    timestamps : false
});


module.exports = AuthDetails;
```

**And, This is my route**

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
// console.log(req.body);

   Users.findOne( { where : { mobile_number: req.body.mobile_number}})
  .then(users => {

  UserAuthDet.findAll({   
    where: {
      client_id: req.body.client_id,
      client_secret: req.body.client_secret
    }
  });
});
```

I'm having the error, while getting the client_id and client_secret from the database.

**My error**

[image]

**UPDATED :** Database.js File

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = new Sequelize('mydbname', 'root', '', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  operatorsAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },

});
```

Comment: do u hv migrations ? or Hw do u create your DB schema ?

Comment: @bereketgebredingle I have updated my code.

Comment: That is for connecting to the database ... I mean can we hv a look at your database schema ?

Comment: @bereketgebredingle You mean this ?  bookshelf, knex , objection , orm , sequelize

Comment: ok.. check your mysql table typo errors change `ID` or `Id` to -->  `id` ;

Comment: I don't know how to implement ORM, OAuth. Because, I'm new to NodeJs. Can you help me

Comment: What does your `Users` table look like?

Comment: @Rastalamm my Users table have 5 columns, id, username, email, password, and mobile_number. But, I got a error on UserAuthDet table. There are two columns in it client_id and client_secret.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `primaryKey: true` to `client_id` in `AuthDetails`.

```
const AuthDetails = db.define('auth_details', {
  client_id : {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  client_secret : {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
},{
  timestamps : false
});
```

I am guessing Sequelize considers `id` as primary key by default unless it is specified and appending `id` to `findAll` query.

ref: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/741

Comment: how about if i dont have id column , this table has generate by a views , can i ignore the item ? the view is union for other tables.

Comment: I am not sure if `view` is supported by Sequelize yet. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7197

Comment: i have generate by raw query on db engine 'mysql' then just define the models for sequelize. ya i know thats not support yet. but i have solve by alternative, set UUID as id then in model sequelize set as primary key .